# Android - Allow user to open text files with app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I fixed my problem with the help of the link to http://www.vogella.com and further searching.

• Android Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:process="IPP.EZPadd">
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".EZPaddActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

• Java Activity:

```
public void open_on_start()
    {
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Uri data = i.getData();
        if (data == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        URL url;
        String startFile = "";
        try
        {
            url = new URL(data.getScheme(), data.getHost(), data.getPath());
            startFile = url.toString().replace("file:", "");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error:\n" + ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (startFile == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();  
        can = false;
        sel = false;
        try
        {
            file = new File(CurDir, startFile);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));  
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                text.append(line);  
                text.append('\n');  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error:\n" + e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        TextEditor.setText(text);
        FileName.setText(startFile);
    }
```

Thank you Simon for the link, it was very helpful. I just skimmed through it at first that is why I ran into that problem with it not loading the file.

Comment: could you please edit your question to clearly delimit both sections: the actual question and the actual answer ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it "by default".  Only the user can choose (and remove or change) the default intent for an action.  Otherwise, it would be chaos!

[EDIT]

Lars Vogel is always a good read.  Try this tutorial.  It's as simple as it gets (almost ;)

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Comment: thats not what I meant, I meant to add the option to open by default.

Comment: Is your question, "how can I make my app appear in the list of apps to handle a particular intent when the user wants to open a text file"?  Sorry, I think I'm confused by your question as much as you are about the subject ;)

Comment: that and how to handle the data passed through my activity they use my app to open it.

Comment: I updated my manifest... It shows up on the open with menu, but it doesn't open the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an intent filter to whatever activity will handle text files. The filters are registered with OS when you install the app. When the user tries to launch a file, Android asks which registered app you want to handle the request.

Comment: I gathered that from the research I did, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: This tutorial on the Android developer page seems to have exactly what you are looking for. Google gave it to me as the first result. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#npex